# Spring - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, spring, post, methods

I'm coding a Spring server and I am using Retrofit to make the api calls.

I have the next interface for the Retrofit client:

```
import retrofit.http.Body;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import retrofit.http.POST;

public interface AuthSvcApi {

    public static final String AUTHENTICATION_PATH = "/authToken";

    @POST(AUTHENTICATION_PATH)
    public boolean loginUser(@Body String accessToken);
}
```

Then my controller is:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.purposes.client.AuthSvcApi;

@Controller
public class AuthSvc{

    @RequestMapping(value=AuthSvcApi.AUTHENTICATION_PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody boolean loginUser(@RequestBody String accessToken) {
        CheckAccessToken checkAccessToken = new CheckFacebookAccessToken();
        checkAccessToken.checkToken(accessToken);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The method isn't finished, but it should work. And the application class is:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;


//Tell Spring to automatically inject any dependencies that are marked in
//our classes with @Autowired
@EnableAutoConfiguration
//Tell Spring to turn on WebMVC (e.g., it should enable the DispatcherServlet
//so that requests can be routed to our Controllers)
@EnableWebMvc
//Tell Spring to go and scan our controller package (and all sub packages) to
//find any Controllers or other components that are part of our applciation.
//Any class in this package that is annotated with @Controller is going to be
//automatically discovered and connected to the DispatcherServlet.
@ComponentScan
//Tell Spring that this object represents a Configuration for the
//application
@Configuration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I don't know why this doesn't work fine, but I am going crazy because the response is:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/authToken] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution, the problem was that the annotation @ComponentScan didn't find the package where the controller was. I resolve the problem indicating to the annotation the package where the controller is.

`@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.purposes.controllers"})`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to include `AuthSvcApi.AUTHENTICATION_PATH`
to this line:

`.setEndpoint(SERVER).build()`

Like this:
`.setEndpoint(SERVER + AuthSvcApi.AUTHENTICATION_PATH).build()`

Comment: I think that it isn't the error, because the end point is the name of the server. I will prove that anyway ;)

Comment: That isn't the problem, the problem was that I needed the @EnableWebMvc annotation in the Application class. Now, I have other problem, I receive the message `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/authToken] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'` because the dispatcherServlet isn't mapping my url.